Confusion on evaluating $S$-Matrix with Interaction turned on in P.Coleman’s Many-Body Physics
I’ve been teaching myself many-body physics with Introduction to Many-Body Physics by Piers Coleman,which is a wonderful book, but I am confused with some details on page 198. All the following equations are written in Interaction Representation. Consider a system with interaction, but the interaction is turned on only between the time period [-T/2,T/2], so we evaluate the $S$-Matrix as:
$$S[T]=\left\langle-\infty\left|\hat{U}(T / 2) \hat{U}^{\dagger}(-T / 2)\right| -\infty\right\rangle.$$
Where $| -\infty\rangle$ is the ground-state without interaction at time $t=-\infty$. And we insert $1=\sum_\lambda|\lambda\rangle\langle\lambda|$, where $|\lambda\rangle$ should be the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian with interaction turned on. So we write:$$S[T]=\sum_\lambda\langle-\infty|\hat{U}(T / 2)| \lambda\rangle\left\langle\lambda\left|U^{\dagger}(-T / 2)\right| \infty\right\rangle.$$ I am fine with all the above steps. What really confuses me is P.Coleman’s statement that ‘In the limit $T \rightarrow \infty$, the only state with an overlap with the time-evolved state $U^{\dagger}(-T / 2)|-\infty\rangle$ will be the true ground state $\left|\psi_g\right\rangle$ of the interacting system’. To be more specific,$$\left\langle-\infty\left|e^{i H_0 T / 2} e^{-i H T / 2}\right| \psi_g\right\rangle$$ is the only term that does not vanish in the limit of $T \rightarrow \infty$. I just fail to figure it out.

The following may help you, I found it to be very useful: "Another proof of Gell-Mann and Low's theorem", L. G. Molinari, Journal of Mathematical Physics 48, 052113 (2007)
https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.math-ph/0612030 (it's on the Gell-Mann theorem but you should get the point).
